# Where to find Quickly app dev tool documentation

Tags: application-development

i want to build an GUI app using Quickly and i would like to get a deeper understanding of how a GUI application is structured, do you know any documentation that might help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to documentation for gtk+ 3, the Gimp Tool Kit. [Here's](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) some documentation on using it using Python. [glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) can also be useful for some purposes.

You can start with simple controls and move to more complex items as you progress.